# Where to use switch_to_locale() WordPress Function?

Tags: php, wordpress

i have made a form in order to switch language using `switch_to_locale()` function

the form is submitted to `admin_url('admin-post.php')`

then i handle it with :

```
add_action('admin_post_change_lang_action', 'switch_site_language');
add_action('admin_post_nopriv_change_lang_action', 'switch_site_language');

function switch_site_language(){
    
    if(isset($_POST['_change_lang_nonce']) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['_change_lang_nonce'], 
                                       'change_lang_action', false) && isset($_POST['lang'])) {
       
         switch_to_locale($_POST['lang']);

    }

    wp_safe_redirect(wp_get_referer());
}
```

but it doesn't work while when i just run switch_to_locale('ru_RU'); from outside it works

is there any problem here

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i actually couldn't find the reason but i found a good way to go over this

i submitted the form like so

```
  <form action="" method="GET">...</form>
```

and for the handler :

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', function () {

    if(isset($_GET['_change_lang_nonce']) && isset($_GET['lang'])){
        
        if(wp_verify_nonce($_GET['_change_lang_nonce'], 'change_lang_action', false)) {
        
            if(switch_to_locale( $_GET['lang'] )){
                wc_add_notice(__('Language changed with success'), 'success' );
            }else{
                wc_add_notice(__( 'Some thing Went Wrong please try later!'), 'error' );
            }

        }else{
            wc_add_notice(__( 'Some thing Went Wrong please try later!'), 'error' );
        }

        wp_safe_redirect(wp_get_referer());
    }
});
```